# Custom login password check with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

If a user tries to log into my Laravel application and the password won't match with the "password" column in the database, I want to check it against another password column ("old_system_password") too.

I'm using the default Laravel authentication system, and as far as I understand I should be able to create a new "AuthController" and override the built in authentication methods. But I don't find any methods dealing with password matching in the vendor folder, and neither do I know how to tell Laravel to use my method instead of the default.

I've searched the web for this, but any solutions I find seems to be only for older versions of Laravel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably try using the Middleware of the authentication looking like this by default:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Try to check if the user has been authenticated then if not call a function that will take your password and check in your database.

Answer (score -1):

First Solution: Just override `public function authenticate()` in LoginController.php

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    } else if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $old_password]) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Check :https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Second Solution:

1:Run `php artisan event:generate` to generate laravel events.

2:Run `php artisan make:event CheckOldPassword`

3:Add Event in EventServiceProvider.php `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed' => ['App\Listeners\CheckOldPassword'],`

4:Create function `public function handle(Failed $event){}`

5:Manually check logins in event.