# Laravel 5.4 with custom login failed to redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, guard

I am facing problem with the login with laravel 5.4 where after successful login user will still redirect to login page.
I have referred to different materials [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication), [custom guard](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-custom-guard-auth) , [custom login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171513/custom-login-password-check-with-laravel-5-4), [Multiple Guard](https://medium.com/@nasrulhazim/laravel-using-different-table-and-guard-for-login-bc426d067901) but I couldnt get the solution on this.
I have also tried to dd($guard) in RedirectIfAuthenticated but returns null.
How to redirect and keep users remain at home page after login?

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogin')->name('login');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogout')->name('logout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister')->name('register');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@postRegister');

// Password reset link request routes...
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

**Login Controller**

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/auth/login';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

     protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('users');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

        if(Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
            return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        $credentials = array(
                'username' => $request->input('username'),
                'password' => $request->input('password'),
        );

        $userData = User::where('username',$request->username)->first();

        if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
                return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'username' => 'This credentials do not match our records.',
                    ]);
    }
```

I have also tried to change the return after success login to return view('home'), able to redirect to the home page but it wont keep the user logged in.

```
if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
                return view('home'); // The changes made
        }
```

***RedirectIfAuthenticated.php***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I have also tried

```
if(Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
```

Comment: Does `Auth::guard('users')->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'));` return true?

Comment: @Autista_z  yes, Auth::check() return true too

Comment: and do you have 2 guards? 1. you are in condition `if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))` and than you make `Auth::guard('users')->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'));` ? isnt it duplicate?

Comment: @Autista_z 
auth() as condition check to run the function , auth::guard to authenticate

Comment: @Autista_z is this the correct way to authenticate? If not please enlighten me, thanks

Comment: auth() uses default guard. So in your case (i think) users. In that case auth()->attempt() is the same as Auth::guard('users')->attempt()

Comment: @Autista_z 
Okay, so now i have modified it 

`if (Auth::guard('users')->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
                return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        }
`
but still failed to redirect
and now auth::check() is false

Comment: So the problem is Auth::guard('users') is not default guard. And you are mixing 2 guards. You have to everywhere use the same guard. So use auth::check() and auth()->attempt(), or Auth::guard('users')->check() and Auth::guard('users')->attempt()

Comment: @Autista_z 
hmm now i see what is the problem here, cause i am mixing 2 guards. If `Auth::guard('users')->check()` then yes it returns true.
How do i return the custom guard back to RedirectIfAuthenticated? This problem might  because the guard was'nt passed to it?

Comment: add conditions in both authenticate and redirectifauthenticated middlewares .. mainly at authenticate to redirect the user to login page if the not authenticated ..

Comment: @VayuDev
I have changed my authenticated to
`protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }`
RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
`public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }`

But still not redirecting to home. What am i missing here?

Comment: @VayuDev for the ease of reading, I have edited on my question. When I try to login and dd($guard) at RedirectIfAuthenticated.php it returns null

Comment: review the whole process once, from defining the guards, customizing the logins. also clear the database (sessions issue). use Auth::guard('users')->attempt() while logging the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

***From***

```
if (auth()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
  {
     return redirect($this->redirectTo);
  }
```

***To***

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
 {
  return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
 }
```

And it works